# NoMethodError on Rails Vulcanize with Rubber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, rubber

I am very new to rails and am trying to get my app setup via rubber. I was able to get a test app up without issue but am running into some sort of error when actually trying to vulcanize my built app. Tried to search high and low to no avail. Anyone have any idea what I need to do to get rid of the issue? Much appreciated.

```
localhost:thiswins markhayden$ rubber vulcanize complete_passenger_nginx_mysql
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rubber-2.2.4/lib/rubber/commands/vulcanize.rb:53:in `block in <class:Vulcanize>': undefined method `-' for "complete_passenger_nginx_mysql":String (NoMethodError)
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/clamp-0.6.0/lib/clamp/attribute/declaration.rb:33:in `instance_exec'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/clamp-0.6.0/lib/clamp/attribute/declaration.rb:33:in `block in define_writer_for'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/clamp-0.6.0/lib/clamp/parameter/parsing.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in parse_parameters'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/clamp-0.6.0/lib/clamp/parameter/parsing.rb:12:in `each'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/clamp-0.6.0/lib/clamp/parameter/parsing.rb:12:in `block in parse_parameters'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/clamp-0.6.0/lib/clamp/parameter/parsing.rb:10:in `each'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/clamp-0.6.0/lib/clamp/parameter/parsing.rb:10:in `parse_parameters'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/clamp-0.6.0/lib/clamp/command.rb:55:in `parse'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/clamp-0.6.0/lib/clamp/command.rb:68:in `run'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/clamp-0.6.0/lib/clamp/subcommand/execution.rb:11:in `execute'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/clamp-0.6.0/lib/clamp/command.rb:69:in `run'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/clamp-0.6.0/lib/clamp/command.rb:127:in `run'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rubber-2.2.4/bin/rubber:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/rubber:19:in `load'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/rubber:19:in `<main>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had this same problem with:

```
rubber vulcanize complete_passenger_postgresql
```

It seems to be an error in the gem at rubber/commands/vulcanize.rb on Line 53 because it tries to subtract an array from a string which is illegal. I changed it to (as sudo):

```
invalid = (arg.kind_of?(String) ? [arg] : arg) - VulcanizeThor.valid_templates
```

This allowed setup however I am not sure if the vulcanization did more than it was supposed to have because I am also new to Rubber. This was a drastic measure so be careful by trying it on a non-production environment first!